# Angular 2 Show and Hide an element

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having a problem hiding and showing an element depending of a boolean variable in Angular 2.

this is the code for the div to show and hide:

```
<div *ngIf="edited==true" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>
```

the variable is "edited" and it's stored in my component:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  (...)
  public edited = false;
  (...)
  saveTodos(): void {
   //show box msg
   this.edited = true;
   //wait 3 Seconds and hide
   setTimeout(function() {
       this.edited = false;
       console.log(this.edited);
   }, 3000);
  }
}
```

The element is hidden, when saveTodos function starts, the element is shown, but after 3 seconds, even if the variable come back to be false, the element does not hide. Why?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You should use the *ngIf Directive

```
<div *ngIf="edited" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  (...)
  public edited = false;
  (...)
  saveTodos(): void {
   //show box msg
   this.edited = true;
   //wait 3 Seconds and hide
   setTimeout(function() {
       this.edited = false;
       console.log(this.edited);
   }.bind(this), 3000);
  }
}
```

---

Update: you are missing the reference to the outer scope when you are inside the Timeout callback.

so add the .bind(this) like I added Above

> Q : edited is a global variable. What would be your approach within a *ngFor-loop? – Blauhirn
>
> A : I would add edit as a property to the object I am iterating over.

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of listOfObjects" *ngIf="obj.edited" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   
  public listOfObjects = [
    {
       name : 'obj - 1',
       edit : false
    },
    {
       name : 'obj - 2',
       edit : false
    },
    {
       name : 'obj - 2',
       edit : false
    } 
  ];
  saveTodos(): void {
   //show box msg
   this.edited = true;
   //wait 3 Seconds and hide
   setTimeout(function() {
       this.edited = false;
       console.log(this.edited);
   }.bind(this), 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: `edited` is a global variable. What would be your approach within a `*ngFor-loop`?

Comment: Edited wouldn't be a global variable, it belongs to the component.
I will add the answer above.

Comment: how to access timer globally from service?

Comment: ngif cause some angular material components fail to initialize and work properly, like mat-paginator.I think using [hidden] is better choice for some cases.

Answer (score 237):

There are two options depending what you want to achieve :

1. You can use the hidden directive to show or hide an element

   ```
   <div [hidden]="!edited" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert">
     <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
   </div>
   ```
2. You can use the ngIf control directive to add or remove the element. This is different of the hidden directive because it does not show / hide the element, but it add / remove from the DOM. You can loose unsaved data of the element. It can be the better choice for an edit component that is cancelled.

   ```
   <div *ngIf="edited" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert"> 
     <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
   </div>
   ```

For you problem of change after 3 seconds, it can be due to incompatibility with setTimeout. Did you include angular2-polyfills.js library in your page ?

Comment: `[hidden]="edited"` doesnt seem to have any effects...?

Comment: In case you have issues with hidden, please follow the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/a/35578093/873282: `[hidden] { display: none !important;}` in your global css.

Answer (score 42):

When you don't care about removing the Html Dom-Element, use *ngIf.

Otherwise, use this:

```
<div [style.visibility]="(numberOfUnreadAlerts == 0) ? 'hidden' : 'visible' ">
   COUNTER: {{numberOfUnreadAlerts}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

For child component to show I was using `*ngif="selectedState == 1"`

Instead of that I used `[hidden]="selectedState!=1"`

It worked for me.. loading the child component properly and after hide and un-hide child component was not undefined after using this.

Answer (score 10):

This is a good use case for an [Angular Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives). Something like this is surprisingly useful.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[removeAfter]'
})
export class RemoveAfter {
  constructor(readonly element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) { }
 
  /**
   * Removes the attributed element after the specified number of milliseconds.
   */
  @Input() removeAfter: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.element.nativeElement.remove();
    }, this.removeAfter);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div [removeAfter]="3000">Removed after 3 seconds</div>
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this will remove the element completely. I changed it to hide, so you could reuse it but that doesn't hide the element presumably due to the `ngIf` is `true`. Is there a way to set the parent's variable that controls this to `false`?

Comment: Can't you just add a hidden class or something instead of calling remove? This technique is pretty generic.

Comment: I think the problem is `ngIf` is more for whether the element is in the DOM or not. What I want is this: `<div [hidden]="messages" [removeAfter]=3000>...` where I show/hide messages if there are any and then remove messages after 3 seconds so user doesn't have to close box. I added your directive above and switched it to do a `hide()` but it doesn't get called when the messages are shown. How do I get it to be invoked on the event? `@Output()` and `EventEmitter`?

Answer (score 8):

**In TS file**

```
showMyContainer: boolean = false;
```

**In HTML**

```
<button (click)="showMyContainer=!showMyContainer">Show/Hide</button>

<div *ngIf="showMyContainer">
     your code
</div>
```

See my **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjzx6h?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

*Happy to hear if someone got helped.*

Answer (score 6):

We can do it by using the below code snippet..

Angular Code:

```js
 export class AppComponent {  
    toggleShowHide: string = "visible";  
 }
```

HTML Template:

```html
  Enter text to hide or show item in bellow: 
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="toggleShowHide">
  <br>
  Toggle Show/hide:
  <div [style.visibility]="toggleShowHide">   
     Final Release Angular 2!
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs, `*ngIf` or `[ngClass]="{hide_element: item.hidden}"` where CSS class `hide_element` is `{ display: none; }`

`*ngIf` can cause issues if you're changing state variables `*ngIf` is removing, in those cases using CSS `display: none;` is required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in HTML attribute that can be used to conditionally hide or show an element which is **[hidden]**.

**NOTE**: This will work on **div** if you try on any other element tag like  this will not work.

**HTML**

```
<div [hidden]="edited" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>
```

**TS file**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  edited: boolean;
  constructor(){}

  // function that does something then updates the edited condition
  func(){

   .....
    this.edited = true;
  }

....
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@inoabrian solution above worked for me. I ran into a situation where I would refresh my page and my hidden element would reappear on my page. Here's what I did to resolve it.

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
public showJoinTodayBtn: boolean = null;

ngOnInit() {
      if (condition is true) {
        this.showJoinTodayBtn = true;
      } else {
        this.showJoinTodayBtn = false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **bind(this)** in your setTimeout function it will start working

```
setTimeout(function() {
       this.edited = false;
       console.log(this.edited);
   }.bind(this), 3000);
```

and in HTML change

```
<div *ngIf="edited==true" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>
```

To

```
<div *ngIf="edited" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <strong>List Saved!</strong> Your changes has been saved.
</div>
```