# what is the difference between [hidden] in the div and using ng-show?

Tags: html, css, angular

I was going through [the Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) and found the following:

```
<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
 class="alert alert-danger">
```

There is no explanation on the `[hidden]` part. Is it a HTML property, CSS or Angular? Why isn't `ng-show` used instead?

Comment: Because ng-show does not exist in angular2?

Comment: `[hidden]="..."` is simply a one-way binding to [the HTML hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).

Comment: still does not answer the [hidden] question?

Comment: @Sarahcartenz doesn't it? Could you clarify what that question is? `[...]` is Angular 2's binding syntax. You seem to be confusing Angular 1 and 2, why reference `ng-show`?

Comment: Either you are meaning angular1 or *gIf directive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of ngShow and ngHide in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-show` is a history of angular1. Before there was no `hidden` property (standard HTML, it is available [starting from ie11](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hidden.asp)) also all standard properties were covered by some similar angular directives which were doing the stuff.

This was a problem because it forced angular programmers to learn lots of directives.

Angular2 idea was to remove all unnecessary directives, and `ng-show` was one of them. Instead, angular2 introduced a property binding `[hidden]` which does the same job.

So the answer is: this is standard HTML property utilized by the angular2 property binding.

Answer (score 2):

`hidden` is [a global HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden). The square brackets indicate a [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#property-binding). Therefore

```
[hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
```

means *"apply the hidden attribute to this element if the specified control is either valid or pristine"*. The browser will then render it but with `display: none`.

You could alternatively use `*ngIf` to remove the element from the rendered DOM entirely, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163376/3001761) for a comparison.

It's unclear why you reference `ng-show`, which was part of Angular 1 and no longer exists in 2.