# Angular 2 hide and show element using *ngIf with boolean

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I want to show and hide an element by using a button that's located in another component.

So I have a Dashboard with an amount of chambers in it and a header.

HTML of DashboardComponent with app-header and app-chamber:

```
 <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <app-chamber [kamers]="kamers"></app-chamber>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have this HTML wth the *ngIf in my ChamberComponent:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 cardcol" *ngFor="let kamer of kamers; let i = index">
      <md-card class="chamber wit" *ngIf="kamer.patient == null">
         <p *ngIf="showId">{{kamer.id}}</p>
      </md-card>
</div>
```

In the HeaderComponent I have a button that needs to show and hide the element :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() aList;

  dashboardComponent:DashboardComponent;

  chamberComponent:ChamberComponent;

  constructor(dashboardComponent: DashboardComponent, chamberComponent:ChamberComponent) {
    this.dashboardComponent = dashboardComponent;
    this.chamberComponent = chamberComponent;

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

// THIS GETS CALLED BY A BUTTON CLICK
  toggleId(){
    this.chamberComponent.toggleId();
  }

}
```

then my ChamberComponent code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chamber',
  templateUrl: './chamber.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chamber.component.css']
})
      export class ChamberComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() kamers;
      showId:boolean;

      constructor() {
        this.showId=false;
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      toggleId = () => {
          this.showId = !this.showId;
      }

    }
```

So when I click the button, the value changes (I've logged this in the console) but the view isn't updated..

When I put a button in my ChamberComponent that calls the toggleId() function the view does reveice an update and the element is shown or hidden.

But I need to toggle it from a button on my header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Show and Hide an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element)

Comment: The duplicate was about 'this' in a callback scope. However my code should work according to that example. this.showId not working..

Comment: If it's not shown or hidden at all, and you have no other content there, are you sure the condition `*ngIf="kamer.patient == null"` is fulfilled?

Comment: Yes I am seeing the element md-card. If I set the boolean showId to true then the id will show up on reload, If I set the boolean showId to false then the id is not showing when I reload the page, but nothing gets updated dynamically when I call the function toggleId

Comment: Could it be that when I call the function of the component from another comonent, this is not working? Because when I call the toggleId() function from within the html of the component itself it is working. However I need to call that function from inside another component

Comment: This is the problem, and this should very much be added to the question as it is very relevant information! So put all related code in the post please! :)

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JBMwKIAu9truFvYdWFQH?p=preview)

There was a small mismatch between the `@Input() kamers` and the template `*ngIf="kamer.patient == null"`.

- Just change the input to `kamer`.

## Template HTML

```
<md-card class="chamber wit" *ngIf="kamer.patient === null">
   <p *ngIf="showId">{{kamer.id}}</p>
</md-card>

<button (click)="toggleId()">Toggle</button>
```

## Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  kamer = {
    patient: null,
    id: '1'
  };
  showId = false;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  toggleId() {
    this.showId = !this.showId;
  }

}
```

## Update (1) - [Plunker (1)](http://plnkr.co/edit/dA7oDKO5IhG9QvWsrqq1?p=preview)

## Use `@ViewChild`

To reference a child component's functions use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

- Place `@ViewChild('child') child;` in the parent component
- In the parent template reference child functions like this: `<button (click)="child.toggleId()">Toggle</button>`

## Parent Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  template: `
    <material-child #child></material-child>
    <button (click)="child.toggleId()">Toggle</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('child') child;

}
```

## Child Template

```
<md-card class="chamber wit" *ngIf="kamer.patient === null">
   <p *ngIf="showId">{{kamer.id}}</p>
</md-card>
```

## Child Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-child',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  kamer = {
    patient: null,
    id: '1'
  };
  showId = false;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  toggleId() {
    this.showId = !this.showId;
  }

}
```

## Update (2) - [Plunker (2)](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5LQLsLkH8hxuEZ3MZWc)

## Use `@Output()` + `EventEmitter`

To extend the previous setup to use a sibling component you can

- Have the sibling emit an event using an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)
- Listen to the emitted event in the parent component, and call the child function needed using `ViewChild`

## Sibling Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-sibling',
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggle.emit()">Toggle</button>
  `
})
export class SiblingComponent {
  @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter();
}
```

## Parent Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  template: `
    <material-child #child></material-child>
    <material-sibling (toggle)="child.toggleId()"></material-sibling>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('child') child;

}
```

## Child Template

```
<md-card class="chamber wit" *ngIf="kamer.patient === null">
   <p *ngIf="showId">{{kamer.id}}</p>
</md-card>
```

## Child Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-child',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  kamer = {
    patient: null,
    id: '1'
  };
  showId = false;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  toggleId() {
    this.showId = !this.showId;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've updated the question with more info. So basically if I follow your advise, I have 2 childs (app-chamber and app-header) of the DashboardComponent. Now your example shows how to call a function of the child from the parent. I need to call a function from a child to another child.

Comment: Maybe the best/easiest solution is to just put the header in the dashboard html and do it like you said?

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it for the sibling setup.. let me know if you need anything else, thanks!

Comment: You sir, are a hero!

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped!