# How to hide PrimeNG sidebar (defined at parent template), when we click on button defined at child template?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG sidebar which slides right and routes to child component when we click on button, there in child component I have form template with button cancel.
you can find sidebar template below.

**sidebar.component.html**

```
<p-sidebar  [(visible)]="visibleSidebar2" position="right [baseZIndex]="10000">
<router-outlet name="createSidebar"></router-outlet>
</p-sidebar>

<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { createSidebar: 'create' } }]" class=" navigation__link" (click)="visibleSidebar2 = true"></a>
```

**child.component.html**

```
 <a   pButton  class="btn btn-default"  (click)="Cancel()">Cancel</a>
```

Now if I click on cancel button the sidebar needs to be hidden. I tried with some stackoverflow answers [Angular 2 hide and show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333807/angular-2-hide-and-show-element-using-ngif-with-boolean)  previously posted but ended up with issue.

Any reply can be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to generate a custom event from child Component and listen for the event on the parent Component.

**Child.Component.ts**

```
import {EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

ChildComponentClass{
@Output() closeClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); // create a new close clicked event

Cancel(){
this.closeClicked.emit(false) // emit the event with boolean value false when Cancel is clicked
}
```

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<Child-Component (closeClicked)="visibleSidebar2=$event"></Child-Component>
```

On the parent component listen for child components `closeClicked` event and you can call a function  and update the `visibleSlidebar2` value inside the function or since you are using two way data-binding for `[(visible)]="visibleSidebar2"` you can just update the value in template as showed.

[For more info Regarding Parent Child Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: @Ramsk is it possible for you to create a plunker ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.layout-container .layout-sidebar{
  display: none !important;
  width: 0px !important;
}
.layout-content-wrapper{
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

use this one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).