# Show/hide angular element by condition

Tags: javascript, angular, onclick, display

I built a feature adding "and zombies" to book names of choice, using basic angular.

```
         <input type="text" ng-model="bookname" onclick="zombies()"> 
            <h1> {{bookname}} </h1>
```

I want the "and zombies" (and the text inserted in the input) to be displayed only when there's text inside the input.

I tries this for starts, just to call the angular using JS and it doesn't work.

```
      <script>
    function zombies() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML = "{{}}" + "and zombies";
    };
    </script>
```

How do I display the text when there's text inside the input?
(please go easy on me, I'm studying alone and you all started as juniors)

Comment: ngIf is what you're looking for : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("h1") is a collection. And you likely want nextSibling instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Show and Hide an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element)

Comment: @LiorShapira you should try this `<h1> {{(bookname)? bookname+' and zombies' : bookname}} </h1> `

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to add the condition which checks the value of `bookname` and display the static content with your name.

Like this -

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bookname" (click)="zombies()"> 
<h1> {{bookname}} <span *ngIf='bookname'>and zombies</span> </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition here.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bookname" onclick="zombies()"> 
<h1 *ngIf="bookname"> {{bookname}} and zombies</h1>
```

Or if you want to use javascript:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bookname" onclick="zombies()"> 
<h1 id="txtheading"></h1> 

function zombies() {
    var heading_value = document.getElementById("txtheading").value;
    document.getElementById("txtheading").innerHTML = heading_value  + " and zombies";
};
```

Comment: It's likely a list - I would find the next H1 sibling

Comment: Playing with DOM elements without requirement is not recommended by Angular

Comment: But OP's primary issue is why it isn't working. Not just providing an alternative solution. Btw I have provided the answer based on angular binding too.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution you don't need onclick function `ng-model` will work itself.

**AngularJs:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bookname">
<h1>{{(bookname)? bookname+' and zombies' : bookname}}</h1>
```

**Angular 2/4/5/6:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bookname">
<h1>{{(bookname)? bookname+' and zombies' : bookname}}</h1>
```