# Conditional rendering with *ngIf Angular 6

Tags: css, angular

I am new to Angular 6 development and I am looking for a solution for the following problem.

I tried to implement the following  which loads with a condition (*ngIf = "showError")

```
<div *ngIf="showError" class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <strong>Alert </strong> Error occured when saving data.
</div>
```

Once it shows in the 1st time when I close this `div` with a close button and then I proceed to generate the same error which means **showError = true** but from 2nd time onward I can't make this div visible due to **this.parentElement.style.display='none'**. How can I solve this to show this div each time `showError = true` even after closing the div before?

Comment: Why not do `onclick="showError = false"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Show and Hide an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it by setting to false

```
<span class="closebtn" (click)="showError = false">&times;</span>
```