# What is the best approach to hide/show component depending on some condition in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

Guys thank you for your help. After getting lots of suggestions and mixed and matched all those suggested code I am able to solve the earlier issue. However I am getting the below error after using @ViewChild decorators in console.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'count1'. Current value: 'count2'.
```

My Parent ts file code is following

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NagivationComponent } from '../nagivation/nagivation.component';
import { CensusComponent } from '../your-data/census/census.component';
import { ApplicationComponent } from '../your-data/application/application.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-data',
  templateUrl: './your-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-data.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class YourDataComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() step;

  count:string = 'count1';
  constructor() {

  }
  @ViewChild(CensusComponent, {static: false}) census: CensusComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.count = this.census.getSection(); 
  }      
}
```

And the your-data.component.html code is following

```
<div [ngSwitch]="count">
   <app-census *ngSwitchCase="'count1'"></app-census>
   <app-application *ngSwitchCase="'count2'"></app-application>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with *ngIf ?

Comment: Where do I need to use *ngIf?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Show and Hide an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue has been resolved to change mode from dev to prod.
in main.ts

```
enableProdMode();
```

Please remove the if condition.
Below is my whole solve code

Parent Component .html file

```
<div [ngSwitch]=count>
      <app-census *ngSwitchCase="'count1'"></app-census>
      <app-application *ngSwitchCase="'count2'"></app-application>
   </div>
```

Parent Component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NagivationComponent } from '../nagivation/nagivation.component';
import { CensusComponent } from '../your-data/census/census.component';
import { ApplicationComponent } from '../your-data/application/application.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-data',
  templateUrl: './your-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-data.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class YourDataComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input() step;

  count:string = 'count1';
  constructor() {

  }
  @ViewChild(CensusComponent, {static: false}) census: CensusComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.count = this.census.getSection(); 
  }

}
```

Child component html

```
<button class="sub btn btn-primary btn-lg nbtn" type="button" (click)="getSection()"><span>NEXT</span></button>
```

Child component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { YourDataComponent } from '../your-data.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-census',
  templateUrl: './census.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./census.component.css']
})
export class CensusComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() count:string;
  getSection(){
    this.count = 'count2';
    return this.count;
  }
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ngIf and in condition use count which will be incremented on click of next button

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='setup-content'>
      <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
      <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
      <app-census *ngIf="count === 1"></app-census>
      <app-census1 *ngIf="count === 2"></app-census1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` to show components based on steps,
try:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='setup-content'>
      <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
      <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
      <app-census *ngIf="step == 1"></app-census>
      <app-census1 *ngIf="step == 2"></app-census1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting the below Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'app-census'. *ngIf only accept Boolean value. Here I need to check a condition.

Comment: @PiyaliGhosh You need to add [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) in your app.module or the module that you declare your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngSwitch` and `*ngSwitchCase` for a cleaner approach when you have more than two steps:

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='setup-content'>
      <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
      <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="count">
          <app-census *ngSwitchCase="1"></app-census>
          <app-census1 *ngSwitchCase="2"></app-census1>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting below error 
src/app/your-data/your-data.component.html:7:36 - error TS2551: Property 'count1' does not exist on type 'YourDataComponent'. Did you mean 'count'?

7         <app-census *ngSwitchCase='count1'></app-census>
                                     ~~~~~~

Comment: You have to set it to *ngSwitchCase="1", not *ngSwitchcase="count1".

Comment: This problem has been solved. However another problem has occurred. I am getting below error after using ViewChild and updating my DOM accordingly. 
core.js:5845 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'count1'. Current value: 'count2'.

Comment: @PiyaliGhosh This is because you're updating the count value in a lifaecycle hook, ngOnInit, ngOnChanges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) or [`*ngSwitchCase`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase) directive to show components based on a condition.

Template:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="step">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'step1'"><app-census1></app-census1></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'step2'"><app-census2></app-census2></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'step3'"><app-census3></app-census3></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'step4'"><app-census4></app-census4></div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>Default</div>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NagivationComponent } from '../nagivation/nagivation.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-data',
  templateUrl: './your-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-data.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class YourDataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() step;
  count:number;
  step: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // here set this.step = 'step1' | 'step2' | 'step3' | 'step4'      
  }
}
```

For stepper based applications, you could refer [here](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples) for a sample application. Enabling the linear mode in that application will make sure you need to enter some data before you can proceed to the next step.

Comment: Getting the below error
src/app/your-data/your-data.component.ts:18:29 - error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

18     this.count = 'count1' | 'count2' | 'count3' | 'count4'

Comment: You need to set the value of `this.step` based on which step you are. For eg., if you are in Step 1, then set `this.step = 'step1';`. This will show the component `<app-census1></app-census1>`. Then when you go to Step 2, set `this.step = 'step2';`. This will show `<app-census2></app-census2>` and so on. `this.step = 'step1' | 'step2' | 'step3' | 'step4'` is supposed to be a placeholder to tell you what values `this.step` can take.

Comment: Also `this.count = 'count1' | 'count2' | 'count3' | 'count4' ` is from the other answer. I use variable `this.step`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***ngTemplateOutlet** to display component based on count variable.

```
 <div class='container'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='setup-content'>
              <h1>Confirm Data/Answer Questions</h1>
              <p>Please answer all questions below. If you have questions about the data provided on this screen, please contact << Broker >> at << Phone >> or << Email >>.</p>
           <div *ngif="count == 1"> 
 <app-census></app-census>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
           </div>
         <div *ngif="count == 2"> 
 <app-census1></app-census1>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
           </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <ng-template #template>
      <router-outlet>
      </router-outlet>
    </ng-template>
```