# Hidding a DIV after a few seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a div that becomes visible / invisible based on a boolean variable.
And i'm trying to add a timeout so my "actions" div could disapear after a few seconds.

This is how my code looks like now.

My html :

```
<div class="text" (mouseenter)="onTextMouseEnter()" (mouseleave)="onTextMouseLeave()">
   <div class="text">
       ...Some Text... 
   <div>
    <div class="actions" *ngIf="showMessageActions">
        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my component methods

```
    onTextMouseEnter(){
        this.showMessageActions=true
    }
    
    onTextMouseLeave(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            this.showMessageActions=false
        }.bind(this), 3000);
    }
```

it's working without the window timeout. And aparently the div disapears when I interact with other component on the screen.

not sure why angular doesn´t update the component after the variable update on the mouse leave event when I tried to use the timer...

I looked for it on the forum and found this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element) but the accepted solution doent's solved the problem. Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Start by getting rid of the function + bind syntax, use an arrow function: `setTimeout(() => this.showMessageActions = false, 3000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ChangeDetectorRef to trigger the detection manually:

```js
  constructor(
    .
    .
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
  }

    onTextMouseEnter(){
        this.showMessageActions = true;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
    
    onTextMouseLeave(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            this.showMessageActions = false;
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        }.bind(this), 3000);
    }
```

Comment: I was looking into this and my component has a change detection strategy    
changeDetection : ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush when I remove this, the weird behavior stops .... Not sure if i can remove this permanently on this code

Comment: if **changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush** used, the above answer can solve your problem, otherwise, you can delete onPush line to make angular work regularly.

Comment: I've tried both way. It works now ! thanks.

Comment: It is more about better performance you can read more on this [link](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/boosting-performance-of-angular-applications-with-manual-change-detection-42cb396110fb)