Remove element with class name
How can I remove the element that has the class loader?
<ngx-supp>
  <div class="ngx-supp-class">
    <div class="loader">...</div>
    <div class="mode">...</div>
  </div>
</ngx-supp>

i tried lik below, but not working
let e = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector("ngx-supp .loader");
this.renderer.removeClass(e.parentNode, e),


That question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009 If it does not answer your question, please clarify why.

Do you want to remove it from the code or the frontend?

Please clarify what "not working" means... Are you receiving any errors? Are you receiving the wrong output? Please [edit] the question and revise - [ask]

@DarkBee I don't get any errors,  not working = Nothing has changed

Use *ngIf or @if to hide and show.
Would recommend going through the control flow methods used in angular - Control flow.
Very rarely angular uses querySelector or plain JS selectors to hide show elements. So go through the official docs, to learn about the angular functionality.
One more thing to note is that showLoader boolean must be defined on the component that contains this HTML since, the ng-content you have added is initialized on the parent component and does not use the component ngx-supp.
Latest versions of angular.
<ngx-supp>
  <div class="ngx-supp-class">
    @if(showLoader) {
        <div class="loader">...</div>
    }
    <div class="mode">...</div>
  </div>
</ngx-supp>

Older versions of angular.
<ngx-supp>
  <div class="ngx-supp-class">
        <div class="loader" *ngIf="showLoader">...</div>
    <div class="mode">...</div>
  </div>
</ngx-supp>

Make sure you have the import CommonModule or NgIf added to imports of either the module or component (standalone).

Try document.querySelector(".loader").remove()
document is referencing the whole page.
querySelector gets the first element with the given attribute.
remove() removes it.
